# How do I get an element by name in Cypress if the name contains a dot?

Tags: cypress

I have some elements that have a dot in the name like the below and I get "Syntax error, unrecognized expression". Is there a way to target those?

```
cy.get('input[name=foo.bar]')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try putting some double-quotes around the attribute value

```js
cy.get('input[name="foo.bar"]')
```